# WP7: Handling Input of a Composite Element

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make my own composite control using this `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:svetlin="clr-namespace:SvetlinAnkov.examples">

    <Style TargetType="svetlin:MyCompositeControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="svetlin:MyCompositeControl">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                        <Button>Click me</Button>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I'd like to "intercept" the touch events, so that they are handled not by the Button, but by `MyCompositeControl`:

```
namespace SvetlinAnkov.examples
{
    public class MyCompositeControl : Control
    {
        private Grid contentGrid;

        public MyCompositeControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCompositeControl);
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            contentGrid = GetTemplateChild("ContentGrid") as Grid;
            contentGrid.ManipulationStarted +=
                new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(
                contentGrid_ManipulationStarted);

            // The same for Delta & Completed
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationStarted(
            ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnManipulationStarted");
        }

        private void contentGrid_ManipulationStarted(
            object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("ManipulationStarted");
        }
    }
}
```

However, even though I'm setting `Handler` to `True`, the button is still getting it. I suppose, it's getting it first.

I then thought that setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` on the button would do it. This time, neither `contentGrid_ManipulationStarted`, nor `MyCompositeControl.OnManipulationStarted` was called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's ridiculously easy. One only has to account for the fact that `Grid` stacks up the elements one over the other and that elements with `Background` set to `Transparent` *still* receive input events.

Here's the `ResourceDictionary`: simply added the `Border` control:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:svetlin="clr-namespace:SvetlinAnkov.examples">

    <Style TargetType="svetlin:MyCompositeControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="svetlin:MyCompositeControl">
                    <Grid>
                        <Button IsHitTestVisible="False">Click me</Button>
                        <Border Background="Transparent" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the C# file is actually simplified:

```
namespace SvetlinAnkov.examples
{
    public class MyCompositeControl : Control
    {
        public MyCompositeControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCompositeControl);
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationStarted(
            ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnManipulationStarted");
        }
    }
}
```